# Find the stationary distribution of a CTMC

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, markov-chains

> Let $\{ X_t : t \geq 0 \}$ be a CTMC on the state space $\Omega = \{ 1,2,3 \}$ with the following transition rates: 
>   $$ \lambda_{12} = 1, \; \; \lambda _{21} = 10 $$
>   $$ \lambda_{23} = 1, \; \; \lambda_{32} = 5 $$
>   and all other rates zero.
>
> Find the stationary distribution $\pi_i$

The generator of this chain is:

$$G =
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 1 & 0 \\
10 & -11 & 1 \\
0 & 5 & -5 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

In class we had a similar example where we looked at $G^2$ and determined $G^n$ from it, but here this gives:

$$ G^2 =
\begin{bmatrix}
11 & -12 & 1 \\
-120 & 136 & -16 \\
50 & -80 & 30 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

which is weird and I don't see any constant $c$ to divide out to apply the technique

$$G^n = (-c)^{n-1} G$$

After this we compute $P_t$, which is pretty simple to find

$$ P_t = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{t^n G^n}{n!} = I + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{t^n (-c)^{n-1}}{n!} G $$

and take $ t \to \infty$ to determine $\pi_i$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, it should be noted that there are [simpler ways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous-time_Markov_chain#Stationary_distribution) to compute the stationary distribution $\pi$.

Your matrix $G$ is diagonalisable. This fact may be useful when computing matrix powers directly, but there is another reason this is useful. You are computing a [matrix exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential).

$$
P_t = e^{t G} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{t^n G^n}{n!}
$$

In the wikipedia article on the matrix exponential there is a [section on computation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential#Computing_the_matrix_exponential), which shows that the diagonalisable case is relatively simple. It does however appear to involve some work to obtain the stationary distribution in this way.

**Calculations using *Mathematica***

*Note that you can follow along with the computations even if you don't have Mathematica, by using the [Wolfram Programming Lab](https://www.wolfram.com/programming-lab/) ([more convenient link](https://lab.open.wolframcloud.com/app/view/newNotebook?ext=nb))*.

Here I describe how we can use the theory above to calculate the $\pi_i$ in a similar way to what you describe, using *Mathematica* to fill in the gaps and to verify the results.

We associate `qM` with $G$ and initialise it accordingly.

```
qM = {{-1, 1, 0}, {10, -11, 1}, {0, 5, -5}};
```

I will first show how we can find the $\pi_i$ more directly. *Mathematica* can immediately find the stationary distribution as follows (no output shown to not spoil the fun).

```
StationaryDistribution@ContinuousMarkovProcess[{1, 0, 0}, qM]
```

This can also be obtained using the following, which corresponds to the technique on wikipedia, i.e. the [simpler way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous-time_Markov_chain#Stationary_distribution).

```
{pi1, pi2, pi3} /. 
  Solve[{pi1, pi2, pi3}. qM == 0 && pi1 + pi2 + pi3 == 1, {pi1, pi2, 
    pi3}] // First
```

Now we return to the problem of using your path to find the stationary distribution. Note that *Mathematica* can also immediately find the matrix exponential of $t G$, without any help. This could be done as follows

```
MatrixExp[t qM]
(*output: big matrix*)
```

In addition *Mathematica* can find the limit of this expression directly.

The more manual approach is to use the fact that $G$ is diagonalisable. We find the eigenvalues `values` and eigenvectors `vectors`

```
{values, vectors} = Eigensystem[qM];
```

These satisfy

```
qM. Transpose@vectors == Transpose[vectors].DiagonalMatrix@values
(*output: True*)
```

In correspondence with the wikipedia article, once we have these `vectors` and `values`, we can compute the matrix exponential. One key fact in the article is that we can easily calculate the matrix exponential of a diagonal matrix, by taking the exponents entry wise.

```
diagExp = DiagonalMatrix[Exp /@ (t values)];
```

We can verify that this is correct as follows

```
MatrixExp[t DiagonalMatrix@values] == 
  diagExp // Simplify
(*output: True*)
```

Now we use the second key fact from the wikipedia article. This fact is that if $A$ is a diagonalisable, i.e. $A = U D U^{-1}$ for some diagonal matrix $D$, then $e^A = U e^D U^{-1}$. So we calculate $e^G$, which we shall call `mExp`, as follows

```
vecInv = Inverse[Transpose@vectors];
mExp = Transpose[vectors].diagExp.vecInv;
```

Again we can verify our result

```
mExp == MatrixExp[t qM] // FullSimplify
(*output: True*)
```

We still have to find the limit as $t \rightarrow \infty$. We could simply let *Mathematica* do the work. The following gives the stationary distribution.

```
First@Limit[mExp, t -> \[Infinity]];
```

To manually calculate this, it seems we should be able to take some shortcuts. However, I will simply show how one entry can be calculated directly. We see that the entry at position $(1,1)$ in our matrix is

```
mExp[[1, 1]] // TeXForm
```

$$
-\frac{1}{112} \sqrt{\frac{5}{13}} \left(\frac{\sqrt{\frac{13}{5}}}{2}-\frac{17}{10}\right) \left(5+\sqrt{65}\right) e^{\frac{1}{2}
   \left(-17-\sqrt{65}\right) t}-\frac{1}{112} \sqrt{\frac{5}{13}} \left(\frac{17}{10}+\frac{\sqrt{\frac{13}{5}}}{2}\right) \left(5-\sqrt{65}\right)
   e^{\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{65}-17\right) t}+\frac{25}{28}
$$

Both terms containing exponentials go to $0$, as both $-17-\sqrt{65} < 0$ and $\sqrt{65}-17 < 0$. Note that these are also the eigenvalues, so that there is probably some additional structure that I missing. Anyway, we see that the limit must be $\pi_1 = \frac{25}{28}$. This corresponds to the alternative methods of computing the stationary distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Note that for all $t>0$, $P(t)=e^{tG}$ satisfies the differential equations \begin{align}P'(t)&=P(t)G\\ P'(t) &= GP(t)
\end{align} 
(known as Kolmogorov's forward and backward equations.) If $\pi$ is a stationary distribution, then $\pi P=\pi$. Differentiating and setting $t=0$ yields $\pi G=0$. Conversely, if $\pi G=0$, multiplying by $P(t)$ yields $\pi G P(t) = \pi P'(t)=0$, so $$\frac{\mathsf d}{\mathsf dt}[\pi P'(t)]=0, $$ which means that $\pi P'(t)$ is constant in $t$ and hence $\pi P(t) = \pi P(0) = \pi$, so that $\pi$ is a stationary distribution.

From this result, we may compute the stationary distribution by solving the system of equations 
\begin{align}
\pi Q &= 0\\
\sum_i \pi_i &= 1.
\end{align}